# Reference to "method" is ambiguous

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camerax

When calling Builder() I am given the error message:

> Reference to 'Builder' is ambiguous, both 'androidx.camera.core.impl.UseCaseConfig.Builder' and 'androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageOutputConfig.Builder' match

The error is produced within the startCamera() function.
**How would I make sure the compiler knows to use the UseCaseConfig option?**
Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time and help.

```
package com.example.atlas2.Activities.Login.UserCreation.ProfilePhotoCamerax;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.impl.PreviewConfig;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Rational;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.atlas2.R;

public class ProfilePhotoActivityX extends AppCompatActivity {


    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA", 
                                                  "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
    TextureView textureView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_photo_x);

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);

        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
        } else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

    private void startCamera() {

        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());

        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder<>();

    }

    private void updateTransform(){
        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        float w = textureView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float h = textureView.getMeasuredHeight();

        float cX = w / 2f;
        float cY = h / 2f;

        int rotationDgr;
        int rotation = (int)textureView.getRotation();

        switch(rotation){
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                rotationDgr = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                rotationDgr = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                rotationDgr = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                rotationDgr = 270;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        mx.postRotate((float)rotationDgr, cX, cY);
        textureView.setTransform(mx);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull 
                                           int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
            if(allPermissionsGranted()){
                startCamera();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted(){

        for(String permission : REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != 
               PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to rename the method name, maybe it is ambiguous with source code.

Comment: @Alex Michael Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - what version of [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) are you using? The latest(at the time of writing) is alpha09(core) in which you should build your preview like this:

```
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
```

You can then easily use whichever set methods in builder for your preview configuration. The [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo) are not completely updated to newest version yet so you can use the [forum](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/forum/#!forum/camerax-developers) for help.